# Gmail like search component

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need a search box, which does something similar to what Gmail search or [Teamcity search](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY) does.

I want to be able to search with prefixes, e.g. `by:my_user in:development`, which would find every "object" (could be whatever), filtered in a meaningful way.

Now, the process of extracting the keys and values and applying them to my dataset, I know how to do. This question is about GUI components.

I want a textbox that can provide suggestions based on my configuration. Is there a javascript component, which does something like this out of the box? Some claim that it can be done with [JQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data), but I'm not sure how.

Comment: I'd suggest doing a regex to parse out all the key(s) (by) and the value(s) (my_user) from the input. Then apply them all one by one on your set of objects

Comment: Certainly. But what I am requesting is a nice GUI component for user input, which can provide suggestions

Comment: Oh I see. Then yes, jQuery Autocomplete, can provide suggestions based on what you return from your back-end code.

Comment: @Eldamir I found this thread, looking for the same thing. Were you able to find anything useful? My context/project is ReastJS/NextJS, but plain HTML/JS/CSS may work too. Thanks!

Comment: @MatiasHerranz sorry bud. Has been a while, so I’m not sure I remember correctly. There was a component called Select2. I think I used that and modified it a bit, but not sure. Happy hunting :)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO You miss a part, the "subject", example

```
var query = "by:my_user in:development the thing";
```

then: find the filters

```
var filters = query.match(/(([\w_]+):([\w_]+))/ig);
```

find the (optional) subject

```
var subject = query.match(/\s([\w\s]+)$/ig);
```

then

```
for(var i in filters) {
    var filter = filters[i].split(':');
    var key = filter[0];
    var obj = filter[1];
}
```

Comment: I guess my question wasn't clear enough. I have rewritten it so it is clearer. I'm not asking about regexes and how to extract meaningful data from a string input. I am asking about GUI components to make the typing of the string more enjoyable